# Setting a collection of related entities in the correct way in EF4 using POCO's (src is the DB)

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, poco

I have a POCO entity `Report` with a collection of a related POCO entity `Reference`. When creating a `Report` I get an `ICollection<int>` of ids. I use this collection to query the reference repository to get an `ICollection<Reference>` like so:

```
from r in referencesRepository.References
where viewModel.ReferenceIds.Contains(r.Id)
select r
```

I would like to connect the collection straight to `Report` like so:

```
report.References = from r in referencesRepository.References
                    where viewModel.ReferenceIds.Contains(r.Id)
                    select r;
```

This doesn't work because `References` is an `ICollection` and the result is an `IEnumerable`. I can do `ToList()`, but I think I will then load all of the references into memory. There also is no `AddRange()` function.

I would like to be able to do this without loading them into memory.

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203744/best-strategy-for-adding-or-updating-a-collection-of-related-entities-when-using) one. There, the only solution was to loop through the items and add them one by one. Except in this question the list of references does not come from the database (which seemed to matter). In my case, the collection *does* come from the database. So I hope that it is somehow possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with entity framework you must load objects into memory if you want to work with them so basically you can do something like this:

```
report.References = (from r in referencesRepository.References
                    where viewModel.ReferenceIds.Contains(r.Id)
                    select r).ToList();
```

Other approach is using dummy objects but it can cause other problems. Dummy object is new instance of `Reference` object which have only Id set to PK of existing object in DB - it will act like that existing object. The problem is that when you add `Report` object to context you must manually set each instance of `Reference` in `ObjectStateManager` to `Unchanged` state otherwise it will insert it to DB.

```
report.References = viewModel.ReferenceIds.Select(i => new Reference { Id = i }).ToList();

// later in Report repository
context.Reports.AddObject(report);
foreach (var reference in report.References)
{
  context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(reference, EntityState.Unchanged);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Dummy approach is interesting. When I notice that this part is causing real performance problems I will probably try that. For now I'll just stick with the ToList approach.